# Android trouble with newline

Tags: android, newline, textview

I have trouble with newline in textview (i read text from assets txt file). See screenshot:

[image]

My code:

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = assetManager.open("book.txt");

         int size = input.available();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
         input.read(buffer);
         input.close();

         String text = new String(buffer);
         txt.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Some lines of book.txt:

> Мим должен молчать
>   Автор pinskiy
>
> --Мама-мама! Смотри! Грустный клоун! – бесцеремонно показывала на него пальцем девочка лет восьми.
>
> -- Маш, это не клоун – это мим, - не сбавляла скорости мама, пытаясь успеть на трамвай. Девочка, не успевая за мамой, болталась у нее на руке, но продолжала гнуть свою линию: «А почему клоун грустный, мама?» - «Спроси у него сама».

Comment: Maybe make a few lines of the book.txt available online so we can see what is in there. Each new line may be a Carraige Return + Line Feed (Windows style) when only the Line Feed is necessary. The funny character you're seeing may be the unneeded Carraige Return (character 0x0D or 13 in decimal).

Comment: In Notepad, when you do **File-Save As** on the bottom you can set the encoding to to **UTF-8**.  If you already saved it as UTF-8, it is something else.  Android uses UTF-8 as the default.

Comment: Looks like a case of `\r\n` newlines. You only need the `\n`. Posting the file as text however doesn't reveal the actual characters in book.txt.

Comment: have u tried my soln provided in this que?? or u have solved it at your own?.

Answer (score 0):

try it once. may it help u.

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

or u can replace that character with "\n"  and now can use this again if that not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I have converted my file from txt to html, and now my code looks like:

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
     InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("book.html");
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     int i;
     try {
     i = inputStream.read();
      while (i != -1)
      {
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
       i = inputStream.read();
      }
      inputStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {

     }

      TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);   
      txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(byteArrayOutputStream.toString()));
```